# Pantheon-terminal is not installed and cannot install it

Tags: pantheon-terminal

I just can't find terminal after shutdown. It was lost from wingpanel, bottom quickpanel. Hotkeys also does not work.

If i try to install pantheon-terminal, it's return:

[image: error while install pantheon-terminal]

Please, help =(

Comment: First of all: **Is your system working fine otherwise?** - Also, if you already have another terminal, try copying and pasting the  output here instead of adding photos of your display. - Further, a good idea might be to disable all third party ppa, do `sudo apt update`, and retry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This only affects people who've added the unstable daily PPA. Don't ever add this PPA on a production system. You will encounter critical bugs while running it. Lots of Loki packages are breaking in daily due to big API breaking changes in Juno. You should purge this PPA and return to the stable software channel.

Answer (score -1):

Temporary use another terminal you can install it from AppCenter
For now there is no solution for this problem :(

UPD: remove daily repo from sources.list and update the system